# In ng6 my directive doesn't refresh my component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive

I have a menu which depends on who's logged in:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/login">Log-in</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/register" *hasClaim="'IsAdmin'">Register</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/about">About</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

I use a directive to show or hide the menu item. When I'm not logged in, the menu item is removed. This is correct. When I am logged in with the proper claim the directive is reporting it is adding the menu item, but I don't see it.

It seems my menu is not refreshed.

My directive:

```
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from '@services/authentication.service';

@Directive({selector: '[hasClaim]'})
export class HasClaimDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }


  @Input() set hasClaim(claimType: any) {
    console.log('In hasClaim input. claimType:', claimType);
    if (this.authenticationService.hasClaim(claimType)) {
      console.log('Add template to DOM', this.templateRef);
      // Add template to DOM
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      console.log('Remove template from DOM');
      // Remove template from DOM
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

My console log before logging in:

```
In hasClaim input. claimType: IsAdmin
has-claim.directive.ts:21 Remove template from DOM
```

My console log after logging in:

```
login successful 
Valid token, current user is set.
Logged in.
Finished login
In canActivate. claimName: undefined
In hasClaim input. claimType: IsAdmin
Add template to DOM
```

The last two lines are from the directive.
It does say `Add template to DOM` but my menu isn't changed.

It seems I'm missing something.

**Edit**:
Inspect element result:

```
<mat-nav-list _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-nav-list" role="navigation">
   <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" routerlink="/login" ng-reflect-router-link="/login" href="/login">
      <div class="mat-list-item-content">
         <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="http://localhost:4250/login"></div>
         <div class="mat-list-text"></div>
         Log-in
      </div>
   </a>
   <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-has-claim": "IsAdmin"
      }-->
   <a _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-list-item" mat-list-item="" routerlink="/about" ng-reflect-router-link="/about" href="/about">
      <div class="mat-list-item-content">
         <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="http://localhost:4250/about"></div>
         <div class="mat-list-text"></div>
         About
      </div>
   </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

`<mat-nav-list>` does not change after logging in.

Comment: Can you check if it is a change detection issue? Try invoking change detection manually after you embed the view.

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh for your quick reply. When I add `this.zone.run(() => this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef));` nothing happens, but when I add `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` after `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)` the menu is not changed but my home component, which shows a list of users (when logged in) goes crazy. It shows my header a huge number of times until `Maximum call stack size exceeded` and no users.

Comment: This is not a change detection issue then. My guess is the template is getting embedded in the view but not in the correct position and with correct style. Can you do an inspect element and search <mat-nav-list> in the dev tool? Also if possible can you post the template code of your directive?

Comment: I've updated my post and added the inspect result. It doesn't seem to change after logging in. I'm not sure what you mean by `post the template code of your directive`. My directive has no template code. The whole code of my directive is in the post.